# Python: Combined lists iteration

Tags: python, list, iteration

I've got two lists:

`synonymes = ['verb1', 'verb2', 'verb3']`

`phrases = ['blabla verb blabla', 'blibli verb blibli', 'verb bloblo bloblo']`

and I would like to combine them to obtain this result in another list:

`liste = ['blabla verb1 blabla','blabla verb2 blabla', ... 'verb3 bloblo bloblo']`

the following code works but it's not very elegant, and I would like to give the 2 lists as entries of the function that's doing this job, which is impossible with this solution:

```
while j < len(synonymes):
    liste.append("blabla "+synonymes[j]+" blabla")
    liste.append("blibli "+synonymes[j]+" blibli")
    liste.append(synonymes[j]+" bloblo bloblo")
    j+=1
```

I can change the structure of these two lists if need be, as long as I can obtain this final list

What would be a proper way to do so in python?

Thanks!

EDIT : to make myself clearer, here is the exact output that I want:

```
["blabla verb1 blabla", "blabla verb2 blabla", "blabla verb3 blabla", "blibli verb1 blabla", "blibli verb2 blibli", "blibli verb3 blibli", "verb1 bloblo bloblo", "verb2 bloblo bloblo", "verb3 bloblo bloblo"]
```

With the length of synonymes and phrases both variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair and [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to replace:

```
>>> synonymes = ['verb1', 'verb2', 'verb3']
>>> phrases = ['blabla verb blabla', 'blibli verb blibli', 'verb bloblo bloblo']
>>> [y.replace('verb', x) for x, y in zip(synonymes, phrases)]
['blabla verb1 blabla', 'blibli verb2 blibli', 'verb3 bloblo bloblo']
```

EDIT:

```
>>> [y.replace('verb', x) for y in phrases for x in synonymes]
['blabla verb1 blabla', 'blabla verb2 blabla', 'blabla verb3 blabla', 'blibli verb1 blibli', 'blibli verb2 blibli', 'blibli verb3 blibli', 'verb1 bloblo bloblo', 'verb2 bloblo bloblo', 'verb3 bloblo bloblo']
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, actually my post was not clear enough but what I need is : ['blabla verb1 blabla', 'blabla verb2 blabla', 'blabla verb3', 'blibli verb1 blibli', 'blibli verb2 blibli', 'blibli verb3 blibli', 'verb1 bloblo bloblo', 'verb2 bloblo bloblo', 'verb3 bloblo' bloblo]. And the length of synonymes and phrases are both variable.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in enumerate(phrases):
    phrases[i[0]] = phrases[i[0]].replace('verb', synonymes[i[0]])
```

or in one line:

```
[phrases[i[0]].replace('verb', synonymes[i[0]]) for i in enumerate(phrases)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same format used in your code

```
liste = [phrase.format(verb=verb) for verb, phrase in zip(synonymes, phrases)]
```

but for make this you have to change the phrases list like this:

```
phrases = ['blabla {verb} blabla','blabla {verb} blabla', ... '{verb} bloblo bloblo']
```

Comment: thank for your answer, I edited my post to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

```
liste = phrases.copy() # create copy of phrases
# iterate phrases with index
for index, verb in enumerate(phrases):
    liste[index] = verb.replace("verb", synonymes[index]) # replace verb with related verb element
```